# Tool to Visualize Timespans across Timezones

Tags: gratis, data-visualization, scheduling, timezones

**Context**: I'm trying to get an overview of when different people around the globe are typically available, based on their typical times of availability and their timezone.

**Software searched for**: A tool that provides a graphical overview of when each of these people are available. *Not* on any particular day. And *not* necessarily with the intention of finding a single time when all of them are available.

**Input**: People (or groups thereof) with phases of availability and their timezone (or location, based upon which the timezone is determined).

**Output**: A picture, possibly looking like a timeline spanning one day, with one bar for each defined person/group, in which timespans of availability are highlighted in some way.

**Bonus points for**:

- The picture might alternatively span a week, in which case the people definitions could distinguish availability timespans by day of week.
- The output is actually multiple pictures, one for each combination of timezones that occur during the year, with the respective validity (e.g. something like "January to March" using daylight-saving time for some of the included places).

Comment: The fun bit would be what to do about changes such as DST which occur on different dates in different locations - should someone be marked as available or not in the gap between 01:59 and 03:00 in spring?

Comment: @SteveBarnes: If one of the places shown in a chart has its DST change on March 5 and another one on March 10, then the result should be (at least) three charts, one valid from the beginning of the year till March 5, one valid between March 5 and March 10, and one from March 10 onward. Anything less than a day doesn't matter; thus the very day where a transition occurs may well be excluded as a "transitory" day for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: The user/group record should also cope with people & groups that spend parts of the year in different locations/TZs presumably.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: At least for my purposes, it doesn't need to be that elaborate. If I need to cover that case, I am fine with adding two distinct "groups" named "Steve in Tokyo" and "Steve in LA" with different locations/timezones.